# "TypeError: schema.validate is not a function" when using joi.assert or joi.attempt

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, joi

I refactored some code that passed on an object as a require to use it from a feature file and now I get the error on the title.

Previously:

```
const schema = require (´path to schema´)
let schemafile = [schema]
```

Now:

```
const schemafile = (fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'path to schema'+schema+.js)toString())
```

the above passed the contents of the joi schema file I prepared, but when i do:

```
joi.assert (responsebody, schemafile)
```

or

```
joi.attempt(responsebody, schemafile)
```

I get the error

> TyperError: schema.validate is not a function

I do have the require for joi, and it seems everything passes fine and the error seems to be internal to joi, as the expression does exist there. What I can't make up is why it used to work before. Rolling back is not an option because I modified many, many files before I got this to hit that part of the code.
Sorry if the code is too vague but I cannot share much more (can't even copypaste from the VDI I use).
I use joi's latest version, I know joi.validate was deprecated and it is not used anywhere in my code.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

PS: I am new to js, node and joi so sorry if the question is too basic.

Comment: Ok after much much much debugging, I realized I am not able to pass Joi.ObjectSchema as a param from the feature file, even if I add a const for the Jpis schema file. There is just no way. If you ever need to know how I bypassed this limitation, drop me a comment.
I had to resort to